# How to fix zoom on webview after open a link

Tags: android, html, webview, zooming, pinchzoom

On my app, i show on a web view an image map at hight resolution, soo the page zoom it's low. 
After clicking on the map, the next page was very very small (bicose users zoom out on previews page)
there're a way to set the web page to fix the webview?
i try with acode, but work only for the first image.
if u need some code, ask me, but it's a classical activity with a web view, and an image map linked to a table.

eg: 
this's the appearence of 3 page on normal user use:
1st page it's the map
2nd page it's a simpel table
3rd page it's another page 
the zoom it's the same from the first page (or of the webview)

[image: first page (map)]
[image: second page, but without zoom reset]
[image: therd page, without zoom reset]

thank's

edit: i've tryed to set the lin to open on a new page, but the zoom level have not change

Answer (score 0):

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
WebViewClient mWebClient = new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            //Reset zoom
            view.setInitialScale(0);
            return false;
        }
    };
webView.setWebViewClient(mWebClient);
```